# multiple file upload in grail

Tags: java, grails

I am trying to copy multiple files using the request or HttpServletRequest features.

I have been able to loop through all the selected files in a controller action where I have accessed the MultipartFile object for each file - here is the action code:

```
request.getFileNames().each{
    request.getFiles(it).each 
    { file ->
        // loop through all files selected
    println "name: $file.name Originalfilename: $file.originalFilename contentType: $file.contentType"
        file.transferTo( new File( userDir, file))                  
    } // eo for loop
} // eo requect.getFiles().each....
```

I get a groovy runtime error at the transferTo line - the error message being:

> Could not find matching constructor for: java.io.File(java.io.File, org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile)

If I comment out the transferTo line the printout line line the loop produces the correct MultipartFile information about each selected files.

See output for two files selected here:

> name: file[] Originalfilename: for-sale.gif contentType: image/gif
>
> name: file[] Originalfilename: front.gif contentType: image/gif

How can I invoke transferTo to do the copy?

-mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for the [CommonsMultiPartFile](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/commons/CommonsMultipartFile.html) you will see that your issue is in the way you are constructing your file.

```
file.transferTo( new File( userDir, file))
```

should be:

```
file.transferTo( new File(userDir, file.getOriginalFilename()))
```

You need to access the `originalFilename` property of the file.

Comment: That works fine - also tried `file.originalFilename` but that failed with a **groovy.lang.MissingMethodException** error and message: `No signature of method: org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile.originalFilename() is applicable for argument types: () values: [] Possible solutions: getOriginalFilename()`.  Yet the print line above displays the originalFilename correctly - not sure why?

Comment: is it possible to run a request commend on a multipartfile object that has been passed to a different action from the initial action that received it that was setup in a input html tag. 
I can access the string in the redirected action - of the **form:org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile@35d79259**

But I  am unable to run a request command such as request.getFiles - also fails if I try to cast it as a MultipartFile.

-mike

Comment: I do not know if you can access a file upload after a redirect or forward from one controller to another. That's a different question than the original question and should be posted separately. Also, if my answer answered your first question it would be helpful to others if you accept it, and if it was a good answer an upvote would be appreciated as well.